# FieldSet background color

Tags: css, telerik, form-designer

I am trying to set a background color for a fieldset in Telerik with the below code.

Can someone point me in right direction, or have any other ideas?

```
.RadForm_Office2007.rfdFieldset fieldset
  { 
  border: solid 1px #080808;
   background-color:yellow !important;

    }

 <telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" 
  DecoratedControls="Fieldset"  Skin="Office2007"/>

 <fieldset style="float: left; width: 280px;">
<legend>Grid
</legend>     
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the background color as

```
<fieldset style="float: left; width: 280px; background-color:red;">
```

you can use color codes for setting background color like this

```
<fieldset style="float: left; width: 280px; background-color:#999999;">
```

you can visit  http://www.colorpicker.com/ for finding color codes

Answer (score 3):

The answer is staring you in the face

```
fieldset
{ 
border: solid 1px #080808;
background-color:yellow !important;

}
```